# Why my code is much slower than opencv for a simple StereoBM algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, stereo-3d

This is my test code for implementation of a simple testBM algorithm, no prefiltering. But it takes around 400 ms or even more when window size is bigger while the StereoBM of opencv (CPU not GPU) takes 20 ms. I have checked the source of StereoBM but it's difficult for me to understand it. Is there anyone who knows why?

And below is my code.

```
void testBM(const Mat &left0, 
            const Mat &right0, 
            Mat &disparity, 
            int SAD, 
            int searchRange)
{
    int cols = left0.cols;
    int rows = left0.rows;
    int total = cols*rows;
    const uchar* data_left = left0.ptr<uchar>(0);
    const uchar* data_right = right0.ptr<uchar>(0);
    uchar* data_dm = new uchar[total];
    int dbNum = 2 * SAD + 1;
    int dNum = dbNum * dbNum;
    //x is col index in the dbNum * dbNum window
    //y is row index in this window
    //z is (x + y * cols).
    //I compute them in advance for avoid computing repeatedly.
    Point3i *dLocDif = new Point3i[dNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < dNum; i++)
    {
        dLocDif[i] = Point3i(i%dbNum - SAD, i / dbNum - SAD, 0);
        dLocDif[i].z = dLocDif[i].x + dLocDif[i].y * cols;
    }

    //I compute disparity difference for eache search range to avoid
    //computing repeatedly.
    uchar* dif_ = new uchar[total*searchRange];
    for (int _search = 0; _search < searchRange; _search++)
    {
        int th = _search * total;
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            int c = i % cols - _search;
            if (c < 0) continue;
            dif_[i+th] = (uchar)std::abs(data_left[i] - data_right[i-_search]);
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < total; p++)
    {
        int min = 50 * dNum;
        int dm = -256;
        int _col = p % cols;
        int _row = p / cols;
        int th = 0;

        //I search for the smallest difference between left and right image
        // using def_.
        for (int _search = 0; _search < searchRange; _search++, th += total)
        {
            if (_col + _search > cols) break;
            int temp = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dNum; i++)
            {
                int _c = _col + dLocDif[i].x;
                if (_c >= cols || _c < 0) continue;
                int _r = _row + dLocDif[i].y;
                if (_r >= rows || _r < 0) continue;
                temp += dif_[th + p + dLocDif[i].z];
                if (temp > min)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (temp < min)
            {
                dm = _search;
                min = temp;
            }
        }
        data_dm[p] = dm;
    }
    disparity = Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, data_dm);
}
```

Here is the essential source code of StereoBM in opencv. I am a little confused after the initialisation. Could anyone explain briefly?

```
static void
findStereoCorrespondenceBM( const Mat& left, const Mat& right,
                            Mat& disp, Mat& cost, const CvStereoBMState& state,
                            uchar* buf, int _dy0, int _dy1 )
{
    const int ALIGN = 16;
    int x, y, d;
    int wsz = state.SADWindowSize, wsz2 = wsz/2;
    int dy0 = MIN(_dy0, wsz2+1), dy1 = MIN(_dy1, wsz2+1);
    int ndisp = state.numberOfDisparities;
    int mindisp = state.minDisparity;
    int lofs = MAX(ndisp - 1 + mindisp, 0);
    int rofs = -MIN(ndisp - 1 + mindisp, 0);
    int width = left.cols, height = left.rows;
    int width1 = width - rofs - ndisp + 1;
    int ftzero = state.preFilterCap;
    int textureThreshold = state.textureThreshold;
    int uniquenessRatio = state.uniquenessRatio;
    short FILTERED = (short)((mindisp - 1) << DISPARITY_SHIFT);

    int *sad, *hsad0, *hsad, *hsad_sub, *htext;
    uchar *cbuf0, *cbuf;
    const uchar* lptr0 = left.data + lofs;
    const uchar* rptr0 = right.data + rofs;
    const uchar *lptr, *lptr_sub, *rptr;
    short* dptr = (short*)disp.data;
    int sstep = (int)left.step;
    int dstep = (int)(disp.step/sizeof(dptr[0]));
    int cstep = (height+dy0+dy1)*ndisp;
    int costbuf = 0;
    int coststep = cost.data ? (int)(cost.step/sizeof(costbuf)) : 0;
    const int TABSZ = 256;
    uchar tab[TABSZ];

    sad = (int*)alignPtr(buf + sizeof(sad[0]), ALIGN);
    hsad0 = (int*)alignPtr(sad + ndisp + 1 + dy0*ndisp, ALIGN);
    htext = (int*)alignPtr((int*)(hsad0 + (height+dy1)*ndisp) + wsz2 + 2, ALIGN);
    cbuf0 = (uchar*)alignPtr((uchar*)(htext + height + wsz2 + 2) + dy0*ndisp, ALIGN);

    for( x = 0; x < TABSZ; x++ )
        tab[x] = (uchar)std::abs(x - ftzero);

    // initialize buffers
    memset( hsad0 - dy0*ndisp, 0, (height + dy0 + dy1)*ndisp*sizeof(hsad0[0]) );
    memset( htext - wsz2 - 1, 0, (height + wsz + 1)*sizeof(htext[0]) );

    for( x = -wsz2-1; x < wsz2; x++ )
    {
        hsad = hsad0 - dy0*ndisp; cbuf = cbuf0 + (x + wsz2 + 1)*cstep - dy0*ndisp;
        lptr = lptr0 + std::min(std::max(x, -lofs), width-lofs-1) - dy0*sstep;
        rptr = rptr0 + std::min(std::max(x, -rofs), width-rofs-1) - dy0*sstep;

        for( y = -dy0; y < height + dy1; y++, hsad += ndisp, cbuf += ndisp, lptr += sstep, rptr += sstep )
        {
            int lval = lptr[0];
            for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
            {
                int diff = std::abs(lval - rptr[d]);
                cbuf[d] = (uchar)diff;
                hsad[d] = (int)(hsad[d] + diff);
            }
            htext[y] += tab[lval];
        }
    }

    // initialize the left and right borders of the disparity map
    for( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    {
        for( x = 0; x < lofs; x++ )
            dptr[y*dstep + x] = FILTERED;
        for( x = lofs + width1; x < width; x++ )
            dptr[y*dstep + x] = FILTERED;
    }
    dptr += lofs;

    for( x = 0; x < width1; x++, dptr++ )
    {
        int* costptr = cost.data ? (int*)cost.data + lofs + x : &costbuf;
        int x0 = x - wsz2 - 1, x1 = x + wsz2;
        const uchar* cbuf_sub = cbuf0 + ((x0 + wsz2 + 1) % (wsz + 1))*cstep - dy0*ndisp;
        cbuf = cbuf0 + ((x1 + wsz2 + 1) % (wsz + 1))*cstep - dy0*ndisp;
        hsad = hsad0 - dy0*ndisp;
        lptr_sub = lptr0 + MIN(MAX(x0, -lofs), width-1-lofs) - dy0*sstep;
        lptr = lptr0 + MIN(MAX(x1, -lofs), width-1-lofs) - dy0*sstep;
        rptr = rptr0 + MIN(MAX(x1, -rofs), width-1-rofs) - dy0*sstep;

        for( y = -dy0; y < height + dy1; y++, cbuf += ndisp, cbuf_sub += ndisp,
             hsad += ndisp, lptr += sstep, lptr_sub += sstep, rptr += sstep )
        {
            int lval = lptr[0];
            for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
            {
                int diff = std::abs(lval - rptr[d]);
                cbuf[d] = (uchar)diff;
                hsad[d] = hsad[d] + diff - cbuf_sub[d];
            }
            htext[y] += tab[lval] - tab[lptr_sub[0]];
        }

        // fill borders
        for( y = dy1; y <= wsz2; y++ )
            htext[height+y] = htext[height+dy1-1];
        for( y = -wsz2-1; y < -dy0; y++ )
            htext[y] = htext[-dy0];

        // initialize sums
        for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
            sad[d] = (int)(hsad0[d-ndisp*dy0]*(wsz2 + 2 - dy0));

        hsad = hsad0 + (1 - dy0)*ndisp;
        for( y = 1 - dy0; y < wsz2; y++, hsad += ndisp )
            for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
                sad[d] = (int)(sad[d] + hsad[d]);
        int tsum = 0;
        for( y = -wsz2-1; y < wsz2; y++ )
            tsum += htext[y];

        // finally, start the real processing
        for( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
        {
            int minsad = INT_MAX, mind = -1;
            hsad = hsad0 + MIN(y + wsz2, height+dy1-1)*ndisp;
            hsad_sub = hsad0 + MAX(y - wsz2 - 1, -dy0)*ndisp;

            for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
            {
                int currsad = sad[d] + hsad[d] - hsad_sub[d];
                sad[d] = currsad;
                if( currsad < minsad )
                {
                    minsad = currsad;
                    mind = d;
                }
            }
            tsum += htext[y + wsz2] - htext[y - wsz2 - 1];
            if( tsum < textureThreshold )
            {
                dptr[y*dstep] = FILTERED;
                continue;
            }

            if( uniquenessRatio > 0 )
            {
                int thresh = minsad + (minsad * uniquenessRatio/100);
                for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
                {
                    if( sad[d] <= thresh && (d < mind-1 || d > mind+1))
                        break;
                }
                if( d < ndisp )
                {
                    dptr[y*dstep] = FILTERED;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            {
            sad[-1] = sad[1];
            sad[ndisp] = sad[ndisp-2];
            int p = sad[mind+1], n = sad[mind-1];
            d = p + n - 2*sad[mind] + std::abs(p - n);
            dptr[y*dstep] = (short)(((ndisp - mind - 1 + mindisp)*256 + (d != 0 ? (p-n)*256/d : 0) + 15) >> 4);
            costptr[y*coststep] = sad[mind];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So does it use the most time in the 'p' loop or in the call to Mat(...)?

Comment: I've checked the time consuming of each step. Before 'p' loop, it takes around 70 ms and 'p' loop uses 320 ms.

Comment: Then I guess `temp += dif_[th + p + dLocDif[i].z];` is the problem, what is the value range of .z?

Comment: I think I should add some commentaries in my code. And the value range of .z is the index difference between each pixel in the window and the center pixel in the window. In fact, the source of opencv that implements StereoBM is not similar as mine. I read the algorithm in "A fast block matching algorthim for stereo correspondence" ([link](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=A+fast+block+matching+algorthim+for+stereo+correspondence&btnG=&hl=zh-CN&as_sdt=0%2C33&as_vis=1))

Comment: A good tool to analyze code performance is callgrind, it provides line by line measurement. It belongs to the valgrind tool suite.

Comment: did you compile in debug mode and/or without optimizations? does opencv use multithreading within that function? opencv will probably use sse instructions and tries to avoid modulo instructions etc.

Comment: In release mode with optimizations. I changed the code to avoid modulo but it helps little... I've added the source of opencv, could you please give me some advice?

Comment: @Seven if you compile the openCV function (maybe renamed) within your own code, is it as fast as if you call it from the library?

Comment: No... around 80ms and have not get a result. And I found that the opencv source code I posted is one thread function. There is some other function using parallel_do and parallel_for_, which, I think, is multi-thread. It's too difficult to understand the source.

Comment: OpenCV executes many algorithms in parallel; parallel_for/do abstract the TBB, PPL and OpenMP backends. I guess that the original image is sub-divided into sub-regions and that `findStereoCorrespondenceBM()` is executed for each of these sub-regions. That is possible with the interface we see since cv::Mat can be used as a view to a sub-image without being required to copy actual pixel data. You can verify this by looking at the processors in use (e.g. with process explorer on windows or `top` on unix) during program execution.

Comment: @HaukeHeibel, I think you are right. My own code is single-thread but opencv does the multi-threads. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV executes many algorithms in parallel; parallel_for/do abstract the TBB, PPL and OpenMP backends.

The original image is sub-divided into sub-regions and `findStereoCorrespondenceBM()` is executed for each of these sub-regions. That is possible with the interface we see since `cv::Mat` can be used as a view to a sub-image without being required to copy actual pixel data. You can verify this by looking at the processors in use (e.g. with process explorer on windows or top on unix) during program execution.

(Originally posted by Hauke Heibel as a comment)